# Using Binding for accessing UI element of parent activity from fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

So, I am trying to migrate from kotlin synthetic to Jetpack view binding.

Here is the kotlin synthetic code (works fine) that simply set visibility to invisible of TextView in the parent activity from fragment.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)

        requireActivity().textView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        return view
    }
}
```

And here is what I'm doing to migrate:

```
import com.mypc.myapp.databinding.FragmentFirstBinding
import com.mypc.myapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
    
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    
    private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
            _binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            return binding.root
        }
    
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
            binding.textView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            binding.textview.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.goto_secondfragment)
        }
        }
    
        override fun onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView()
            _binding = null
        }
    }
```

I'm getting error as 'Unsolved reference' at 'textview':

```
binding.textView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

And at:

```
binding.textview.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.goto_secondfragment)
        }
```

Obviously the compiler is not able to find TextView that is in Activity
I've added this line:

```
import com.mypc.myapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `binding` is private to `MainActivity` you can refer to your `textView` from the `MainActivity` only. To show/hide this view from `FirstFragment` you can create a public function in `MainActivity` and call it from your `FirstFragment`.

```kotlin
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity {

    private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    fun showHideTextView(visible: Boolean) {
        binding.textView.isVisible = visible
    }
}
```

And in your fragment, you can call:

```kotlin
(requireActivity() as MainActivity).showHideTextView(false) // This will hide the textView
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but I also need to impletemt this `binding.textview.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.goto_details) }`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to add this to a function in the activity and calling it from fragment

Comment: I've updated the question for better understanding

Comment: You can set the click listener in the activity itself. When the listener is invoked  check which is the topmost fragment in the backstack. If it is `FirstFragment`, you can execute the corresponding code there.

Comment: @notBot Didn't this code meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should define instance of activity view binding in baseActivity which is a parent class of your MainActivity, and then define method to change your text view like 'showTextView' , after that in the base fragment class initalize base activity instance with casting context object in onAttach method.
I provide you some code:

```
abstract class BaseRegisterActivity : BaseActivity() {

    //---

    protected lateinit var binding: ActivityRegisterBinding

    private val navHostFragment by lazy {
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as 
        NavHostFragment
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_register)

        //---
    }

     fun showTextView() {
        binding.textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.textView.setOnClickListener {
            val fragment =
                navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments[0]

            if (fragment is FirstFragment) {
               //todo
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment(), Injectable {

    //--

    lateinit var baseActivity: BaseRegisterActivity

   
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        baseActivity = context as BaseRegisterActivity
    }
    
    
    //--
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question for better understanding. Kindly check

Answer (score 0):

```
class ShopFragment : Fragment() {

var binding:FragmentShopBinding ?= null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = FragmentShopBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
    
    return binding?.root
}
```